# Converting column data decimal into ip address in R

Tags: r, loops, csv, iptools

Let's say I have the following

```
 Col A

16777216 
16812288 
16813568
16785408
```

so on and so for in column A (2500 rows of data), all these are decimal values, I will like to convert them using a library package in R, iptools by using iptools::numeric_to_ip function by each of their row data and replace them, how can i dynamically do it looping through all the values and replacing it without hardcoding the values in?

Further on, I have another column which states the end value of the IP, i will like to know how to find out how to find the country (yet another column C) when a PARTICULAR ip address falls into this range of start IP and end IP address, but i guess i will leave it to another question.

Appreciated if you guys can shed some light on this, really new to R.

Cheers,
TechNewbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have a data table with your data:

```
library(data.table)
library(iptools)
test <- data.table(V1 = c(16777216, 16812288, 16813568, 16785408), 
V2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
V3 = c("122.0.0.0", "1.0.1.0", "172.16.0.1", "192.168.1.1"))

         V1 V2          V3
1: 16777216  A   122.0.0.0
2: 16812288  B     1.0.1.0
3: 16813568  C  172.16.0.1
4: 16785408  D 192.168.1.1
```

In order to convert each value to a valid IP, you could use this simple syntax:

```
test[, V1 := numeric_to_ip(V1)]

          V1 V2          V3
1:   1.0.0.0  A   122.0.0.0
2: 1.0.137.0  B     1.0.1.0
3: 1.0.142.0  C  172.16.0.1
4:  1.0.32.0  D 192.168.1.1
```

What this structure does is iterate through each row of your column (V1) and modify the value returned from the call to `numeric_to_ip()`. [Here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf) is a great summary of the amount of operations that you can do with data tables.

Of course, you could also use the same approach in order to detect which IPs are in a particular range:

```
test[, V4 := ip_in_range(V1, "1.0.0.0/24")]

          V1 V2          V3    V4
1:   1.0.0.0  A   122.0.0.0  TRUE
2: 1.0.137.0  B     1.0.1.0 FALSE
3: 1.0.142.0  C  172.16.0.1 FALSE
4:  1.0.32.0  D 192.168.1.1 FALSE
```

Or compare if two IPs in one row are within the same range (using the iptools library):

```
test[, V4 := ifelse(ip_in_range(V1, V3), TRUE, FALSE)]

          V1 V2          V3    V4
1:   1.0.0.0  A   122.0.0.0 FALSE
2: 1.0.137.0  B     1.0.1.0 FALSE
3: 1.0.142.0  C  172.16.0.1 FALSE
4:  1.0.32.0  D 192.168.1.1 FALSE
```

Or maybe define your own function and compare the values according to other criteria:

```
compareTwoIPs <- function(ip1, ip2){
   # do whatever you want
}

test[, Result := compareTwoIPs(V1, V3)]
```

Comment: `numeric_to_ip` and such are not `data.table` operations.  What package did you use?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I used `iptools`. The user who asked the question mentioned that package in the description.

Comment: @JaimeCaffarel Hi, is there a way to load the column values dynamically inside the data frame without having to type it out statically like what you did because my data is dynamic instead of static - it changes.

Comment: @JaimeCaffarel Hi! It's okay, I figured it out, thanks alot for the answer and the cheat sheet! It really helped. Cheers ;)